# Using external library for Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 + Angular CLI to build an app. I found this cool library '[csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson#library)' that does exactly what I wanted based on the demo
So I am trying to include it in my project. However, My first question is, is it possible to include this library in my project as I dont see it being built for Angular 2?
If no... does that mean i can only simply look away and feel sad?

If yes... how would I implement it. What I have done below does not work

```
1. npm i --save csvtojson
2. inside app.module.ts 
    import { csvtojson } from 'csvtojson'
    providers: [
      {{...}}
      csvtojson //test
    ],

3. app.component.ts
    import { csvtojson } from 'csvtojson'
    constructor(private csvToJson: csvtojson) { }
    this.csvToJson.csv({ noheader: true })
        .fromString(data)
        .on('csv', (csvRow) => { // this func will be called 3 times
             console.log('afasf',csvRow) // => [1,2,3] , [4,5,6]  , [7,8,9]
        })
        .on('done', () => {
            //parsing finished
        })
```

And I get this error

> ERROR in ./~/csvtojson/libs/core/workerMgr.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/james/Desktop/web-app/nod
>   e_modules/csvtojson/libs/core'

Answer (score 0):

because this libs need run on node server, you can not have `child_process` in browser.

for browser, this solution could help you https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-ask-ben-parsing-csv-strings-with-javascript-exec-regular-expression-command.htm

Comment: does that mean this library is simply out of my reach?

Comment: for browser you could use this solution https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-ask-ben-parsing-csv-strings-with-javascript-exec-regular-expression-command.htm

Answer (score 0):

No need for External Library.

Here working Plunker for [csvTOjson](https://plnkr.co/edit/DE80sO)

```
    import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
    import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'csvTOjson works!';
      text  : any ;
      JSONData : any;
      csvJSON(csvText) {
       var lines = csvText.split("\n");

       var result = [];

       var headers = lines[0].split(",");
       console.log(headers);
       for (var i = 1; i < lines.length-1; i++) {

           var obj = {};
           var currentline = lines[i].split(",");

           for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
               obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
           }

           result.push(obj);

       }

       //return result; //JavaScript object
       console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); //JSON
       this.JSONData = JSON.stringify(result);
    }

     convertFile(input) {

     const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
     reader.onload = () => {
       let text = reader.result;
       this.text = text;
       console.log(text);
       this.csvJSON(text);
     };

    }
    }


    @NgModule({
      imports: [ BrowserModule ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```